# jQuery DataTable - Displaying data with custom JSON structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

How to populate custom JSON data structure using jQuery Datatable. I found below solution(Datatable default - JSON structure) and it's working fine until I have 'Data" as main object/array, however, I want to utilize another JSON structure(My JSON structure). Is it possible or do I need to stick with Datatable default JSON structure? I am using DataTables 1.10.7. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Datatable default - JSON Structure**

```
{
 "data": [
{
  "name": "Tiger Nixon",
  "position": "System Architect",
  "salary": "$320,800",
  "start_date": "2011/04/25",
  "office": "Edinburgh",
  "extn": "5421"
},
{
  "name": "Garrett Winters",
  "position": "Accountant",
  "salary": "$170,750",
  "start_date": "2011/07/25",
  "office": "Tokyo",
  "extn": "8422"
}
]
}
```

My JSON structure

```
[
{
  "Date": "12/04/14",
  "MeterID": "56",
  "BlockID": "12",
  "Type": "sure",
  "Subtype": "truction",
  "Notes": ""
},
{
  "Date": "12/04/14",
  "MeterID": "3456",
  "BlockID": "123456",
  "Type": "alism",
  "Subtype": "working",
  "Notes": "Lorem"
}
]
```

jQuery Datatable code snippet

```
$('#incident').DataTable({
    "ajax": "../../data/object.json",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "salary" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "extn" }
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 10
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [solution](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxDataProp), it will solve your query..

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it.

```
$('#divWorkQueueTable').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="workQueueTable"></table>');
    $('#workQueueTable').DataTable({
        "data": requests,
        "columns": [{
            "title": 'ID',
            "data": "ID",
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "render": function(data) {
                return '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="modARBRequest.Load( \'' + data + '\')">' + data + '</a>';
            }
        }, {
            "title": "Project ID",
            "data": "ProjectID",
            "sWidth": "10%"
        }, {
            "title": "Phase",
            "data": "Phase",
            "sWidth": "5%"
        }, {
            "title": "Project Description",
            "data": "Title",
            "sWidth": "50%"
        }, {
            "title": "Date Requested",
            "data": "DateRequested",
            "sWidth": "10%",
            "render": function(data) {
                return modCommon.DateToString(data);
            }
        }, {
            "title": "Stage",
            "data": "Stage",
            "sWidth": "15%"
        }, {
            "title": "Status",
            "data": "Status",
            "sWidth": "10%"
        }]
    });
```

So if I were you I would attempt to resolve the ajax request and pass the resolved data into the data table.  Looking at your "data" lines they don't seem to correspond to your json.  Am I missing something?

so you would need something like "data":"Date", "data": "MeterID", "data": "BlockID" etc...

```
$('#incident').DataTable({
"ajax": "../../data/object.json",
"columns": [
    { "data": "Date" },
    { "data": "MeterID" },
    { "data": "BlockID" },
    { "data": "Type" },
    { "data": "Subtype" },
    { "data": "Notes" }
],
"iDisplayLength": 10
```

})

Comment: Data lines(JSON file) represents the data structure mentioned as My JSON structure, also I am not able to understand the above solution :-(

Comment: you would need something like "data":"Date", "data": "MeterID", "data": "BlockID" etc...

Comment: See my additional clarification in the initial response.  I would also use the title property for your column header and make your widths on the actual column through the sWidth.

Comment: please post the file then.  Have you tried changing the names of the fields in the output as I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I tried, it says - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: please post that attempt so I can see.